# How to exit web2py from browser or on tab closure

Tags: python, batch-file, web2py

I am trying to build a really simple and user friendly web2py app and I am a beginner web2py-er.
I am using a bat file to launch my source web2py version (compiled web2py.exe launcher is not an option b/c of dependencies). 
How can I build a functionality where the user can exit with a single button click from the browser or have a way to exit web2py cleanly after tab closure is detected? Either method works. Some ideas I had - I know I can run a taskkill with the pid but I cannot output that variable pid to a text file so that I can read it later. My output file is empty (see below). Any ideas?

```
cd %~dp0
start python web2py.py -p 8004 -a t > mynetworksettings.txt
timeout /T 4 /NOBREAK
start "" http://127.0.0.1:8004/mytool/default/1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: web2py writes the current PID to a "httpserver.pid" text file with every instantiation. Will read that directly.